# Restrict Category Assignment To A Single Leaf Node

Tags: channel-entries, categories

Is it possible in CPanel to restrict the assignment of a channel entry to a single leaf node category? My categories are hierarchical and only a single, bottom-most category is valid per channel entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Lonely Cat
Which will set a single category.
Possibly needs @Cheyney's answer too (Not auto-assign category parents)
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lonely-cat

Answer (score 2):

"Assign", yes. "Restrict", no. Unless you find a plugin.

You can ensure that an entry is NOT assigned to categories above the node chosen by setting "Auto-Assign Category Parents" to "No".

[image: Setting: Auto-Assign Category Parents]